# Special reader macros like [ ], { }

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to write some special reader macros:

```
[hello "world"] ; <=> (funcall #'|hello| "world")
{hello "my" ("world")} ; <=> (apply #'|hello| "my" ("world"))
```

Can this be implemented? And how would you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the term you are wanting is `readtable` ([Common Lisp HyperSpec chapter 23](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/23_.htm) and [Common Lisp HyperSpec chapter 2](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_.htm) talk about the relevant concepts).

You'll need to first define a function that can read the data you are interested in, then return it in the form you want it.

```
(defun read-case-preserve-funcall-or-apply (stream char)
  (let ((preserved-readtable-case (readtable-case *readtable*)))
    (setf (readtable-case *readtable* :preserve))
    (let ((tmp (read-delimited-list (if (char= char #\[) #\] #\}) stream t)))
      (let ((fun (car tmp))
        (args (cdr tmp)))
    (cond ((char= char #\[) `(funcall (function ,fun) ,@args))
          ((char= char #\{) `(apply (function ,fun) ,@args)))))))
```

After that, you need to hook it up to the readtable and copy some syntax-markers from `(` and `)` to your new delimiters.

Comment: I would also suggest to do it using the [named-readtales](http://common-lisp.net/project/named-readtables/) library, which will allow you to compose different readtable modifications and help avoid messing around with other people's ones